# Floating Action Button in an Activity with RecyclerView doesn't receive onClick

Tags: android, kotlin

Tap action on floating action button doesn't work.

I'm learning android RecyclerView, I'm able to populate the activity with data. I also have FloatingActionButton at the bottom of the activity, which doesn't respond to touch events. Eventhough listener is attached to the button, nothing happens when I tap it.

EventsActivity.kt

```
class EventsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        //MY FAB BUTTON IS ATTACHED WITH LISTENER HERE
        addEvent.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }

        ...

        setupRecyclerAdapter()
    }
}
```

activity_events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>

    </data>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".events.EventsActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <include android:id="@+id/content_events"
                 layout="@layout/content_events"/>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/addEvent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

[image: FabGif]

Comment: I would suggest to remove the <include> tag, comment out the code part and test.

Comment: Still not working. This activity is presented as result of clicking an item in NavigationDrawer from MainActivity. Would there be a problem there?

Comment: Can you share your project?

Comment: https://github.com/sarawanakumar/Rachu

Comment: working well for me

Comment: Okay! not sure what's wrong!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194553/discussion-between-sarawanak-and-rahul-shukla).

Comment: Having the same problem. You find a fix yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
addEvent.setOnClickListener(this)

override fun onClick(v: View?)
{
   when(v!!.id)
    {
        R.id. addEvent ->
    {
       Log.i("FABCLICK","Click on Fab icon")
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to print  log or Toast instead of Snackbar?

before

```
  addEvent.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
```

after

```
  addEvent.setOnClickListener { view ->
       val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Hello Javatpoint", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)  
        toast.show()  
    }
```

Comment: Not able to see the toast too. Guess the button doesn't register event at all. I'll post a gif of the view soon. That may help.

Comment: refer  this for layout https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource